# Difficulty Leading Zeroes Problem

Tags: mining-theory

Bitcoin mining difficulty always increases, meaning the target decreases. There is only 256 bits in SHA256 number. Can the difficulty theoretically get to 0, meaning that for the block to be mined, the hash has to be equal to zero (all leading 0s). It will mean that it cannot decrease lower, therefore killing the difficulty adjustment.

So, is this impossible even with quantum computing, or if it is, what will we do? Hard fork?

Thanks